# How do I retrieve Lightning Web Components using Ant Migration tool or mdapi:retrieve command from SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, ant, migration-tool, lightning-web-components

This is not clear or obvious how can anyone retrieve Lightning Web Components using `Ant Migration tool` or `mdapi:retrieve` command from `SFDX`?

What is appropriate metadata API component which corresponds to LWC folder components in sfdx?

What should be included in `package.xml`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The new Metadata API component is called [LightningComponentBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningcomponentbundle.htm)

The following XML code should be added to package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other part of this post was about using SFDX Commands in the Terminal window of VS Code

`sfdx force:source:deploy -m LightningComponentBundle -u <connected/authorized org alias>`

-m switch allows you to do partial deployments as opposed to building an ANT package.xml file, but beware that you ensure you've included all the dependent elements.  You can deploy multiple elements with -m switch as comma delimited.  Use --help for more assistance on force:source:deploy or force:mdapi:deploy

Answer (score -2):

This issue has since been resolved (as of April 11, 2019) in version 7.3.0 of the Salesforce CLI.
[GitHub issue 1072](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1072)

---

Here's an interesting side affect of that, at least for the moment.
If you use the process here:
[Org Development Model with VS Code](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model)

The **SFDX: Create Project with Manifest** command DOES NOT include Lightning Component Bundle in the package.xml it creates. So while it will create a **force-app/lwc** directory it will not retrieve anything.

Comment: This does not appear to be valid. I just did this myself and it did infact include Lightning component bundles and Lightning web components.